# How to decode oulook personal account access_token using MSAL.js

Tags: jwt, token, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have acquired access_token on behalf of user for personal outlook account

Below is the token, but I could not able to decode it using https://jwt.io/ OR npm package `jwt-decode`

> 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

Please help if you have any idea

Comment: I can use this token to call GraphAPIs. It works fine. The only issue is to decode it to extract the EXP value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot decode the access token from the Personal account as they aren't validated as JWT. Instead they are encrypting it.

> Don't attempt to validate or read tokens for any API you don't own,
> including the tokens in this example, in your code. Tokens for
> Microsoft services can use a special format that will not validate as
> a JWT, and may also be encrypted for consumer (Microsoft account)
> users. While reading tokens is a useful debugging and learning tool,
> do not take dependencies on this in your code or assume specifics
> about tokens that aren't for an API you control.

ref: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code#:~:text=Don%27t%20attempt%20to,API%20you%20control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20attempt%20to,API%20you%20control).

Comment: [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)